# Geodesics of a cone

Tags: calculus, geometry, calculus-of-variations

To find Geodesics on a cone I used the cylindial coordinates
$x=rcos\theta$
$y=rsin\theta$
$z=z$

**Is this parameterization correct.How can I know how to parameterize?**

Then arc length $ds^2=r^2 d^2\theta+dz^2$
$dz=\sqrt{r^2 +({dz\over d\theta})^2}d\theta$
 Lagrangian = $\sqrt{r^2 +({dz\over d\theta})^2}=L(\theta,z,z')$

Since Lagrangian does not depend on $\theta $ I used the Theorem on Hamiltonian function as
$H(u,u')=L(u,u')-u'{\partial L \over\partial u'}$ is a first integral for the Euler Lagrange equation meaning that it is constant on each solution.

Then I end up with $H(z,z')={r^2 \over \sqrt{r^2+(z')^2}}$.Thus ${r^2 \over \sqrt{r^2+(z')^2}}=k$,where k is a constant.
And integrating $z={r\theta\over k}\sqrt{r^2-k^2}+m$, m is a constant of integration.
I want to know if what I have done is correct. And is solving for $z $ alone is enough

Comment: A note regarding the parametrization: In cylindrical coordinates, you can parametrize a cone using $\theta$ and just one of $r$ or $z$.

Comment: You should specify the cone you want to use. Is it a revolution of $y=|x|$?

Comment: @user153841 I did geodesic for a sphere.I thought I could just try out a cone as well.This is not a given problem.I just made this up.So it's not specifically $y=|x|$ ?Can't I do this for a general case?Also is my cylindrical coordinates wrong?Is there a method or theory behind coming up with spherical and cylindrical coordinates

Comment: To parametrize a surface, you need to use *two* variables, not three. I would recommend $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, $z=r$ (or $z=2r$ or ...). Now you should get $ds^2 = 2dr^2+ r^2\,d\theta^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin :How was $z=r$ picked?I don't understand how these parameterizations are done.What's the basis of selecting$ z=r $or $z=2r$

Comment: Well, decide what your cone is!! Presumably its equation is $z=c\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for some $c>0$. I picked $c=1$ or $c=2$, etc. The coefficient of $dr^2$ in the metric will depend on $c$, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin : So every time I am making a parameterization and if n variables are there and if I have written n-1 variables as parameterized, the nth one should be written in using the others?

Comment: It depends what the dimension of your manifold (higher-dimensional surface) is. $k$-dimensional means $k$ parameters. Curves take one, surfaces take two.

Comment: @TedShifrin :Thanks